# Using Django to extract results from SQL (multiple db's)

Tags: sql-server, django, django-orm

If anyone can think of a more appropriate title for this question then I am all ears.

I've inherited an sql script that gathers information for a report from 3 databases, using a lot of #temporary tables to store filtered data. I need to use the output of this script to generate the reports using Django.

I've started by inspectdb'ing the dbs I need and making models for the necessary tables. My original plan was to reverse-engineer the sql script (~330 lines & 20 queries), but this is proving to be much trickier than I thought. Is there a way for me to run this script and save the #temporary tables to Django models in another db or something?

I'm using Django 1.5 and MS SQL Server 2008 R2 (with django-mssql backend). Thank you for your time.

==EDIT==

I'm going to expand on how this script is structured a little bit:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
declare variables here
set them here

SELECT f.val1, b.val2
INTO #temp_table1
FROM myDB1.dbo.foo f,
     myDB1.dbo.bar b,
     myDB2.dbo.foobar fb
WHERE ...
etc

-- followed by lots more selections --
.
.
.
SET NOCOUNT OFF

SELECT
        [22 things get selected and manipulated here]
        [This is the data I really want]
FROM
        [mixture of #temp tables and myDB1]
WHERE [...]
GROUP BY [...]
ORDER BY [...]

SET NOCOUNT ON
DROP TABLE #temp_table1
.
.
.

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Django model for each of your temp tables.  In each model, I would define an `import(self)` method that truncates the table and selects all the rows.

Your other code would decide when to import data for each temp table.  Maybe it doesn't need to be imported every single time, so you could optimize the imports to only load data that has changed since the last time it was imported.

Then you could use Django queries to perform your SELECTs.